# Ubuntu external monitor crash

Tags: nvidia, monitor

My laptop is a Lenovo IdeaPad L340 Gaming with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 and I have been using Ubuntu on this machine for years. Still, in the last couple of months, Ubuntu crashes all the time after a couple of minutes, displaying a white/purple/green screen. This **only happens when the external monitor is connected to the HDMI port** and the only way to recover is by forcing the restart. Sometimes after the restart, Ubuntu does not recognize the Nvidia card and I need to purge and reinstall the drivers again. Right now I using nvidia-driver-15 but I already tested several drivers without luck.

**UPDATED**
I got the following from the `kern.log`

```
ul  8 10:34:34 jegj-laptop kernel: [ 3875.273808] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 79, pid=2510, name=Xorg, GPU has fallen off the bus.
Jul  8 10:34:34 jegj-laptop kernel: [ 3875.273811] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: GPU has fallen off the bus.
Jul  8 10:34:34 jegj-laptop kernel: [ 3875.322047] NVRM: A GPU crash dump has been created. If possible, please run
Jul  8 10:34:34 jegj-laptop kernel: [ 3875.322047] NVRM: nvidia-bug-report.sh as root to collect this data before
Jul  8 10:34:34 jegj-laptop kernel: [ 3875.322047] NVRM: the NVIDIA kernel module is unloaded.
Jul  8 10:34:34 jegj-laptop kernel: [ 3875.370587] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 62, pid=2510, name=Xorg, ffffffff(ffffffff) ffffffff ffffffff
Jul  8 10:34:34 jegj-laptop kernel: [ 3875.370727] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Failed to query display engine channel state: 0x0000927c:0:0:0x00000040
```

Comment: Have you checked the logfiles for any hints?

Comment: @Marco i updated the question with information from the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of installing and purging Nvidia drivers and trying several solutions without luck, I found the following link: https://ubuntuperonista.blogspot.com/2020/07/como-soluciono-el-error-nvrm-gpu-nvidia-ubuntu-persistance-mode.html. It is Spanish, but basically says that we need to enable the persistence mode with the following command:

```
sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-smi -pm 1
```

The previous command works for me and avoids Ubuntu crash with an external monitor and fix the error related to `GPU has fallen off the bus`  but you need to run the command every time after restarts so I create a cron entry at @reboot time to enable the persistence mode always:

```
@reboot sleep 100 && /usr/bin/nvidia-smi -pm 1
```

This works for me but I also found an entry in the Nvidia blog, saying that the command is deprecated and there is a systemd unit in charge of the persistence: `nvidia-persistenced`. I tried enabling this unit but still getting crashes...could be a bug ? ... who knows... but I am happy with the previous command.

Comment: This was just a temporal solution for a couple of days but then after several days the same problem continued to happen. At the end my Nvidia card was having problem and died ( could not recognize the device) leaving my laptop useless